# No response in console to jquery ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

[image]

I am making the following jquery ajax call to a codeigniter php function:

```
    $.ajax({
                        type:"POST",
                        url: "AjaxUpdate/getHtml",
                        data:{ u : 'http://stackoverflow.com/' },
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log(data);

                        },

                       error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                console.log('error');
                                console.log(jqXHR,textStatus, errorThrown);
                        }
                    });
```

The requested php function is :

```
public function getHtml() {

        $url = $_POST['u'];
        $result = file_get_contents($url);
        return json_encode($result);
}
```

How can I fix this?

edit: the error in the console shows:

```
error
reply_detail:4667 Object {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…} "parsererror" SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input {stack: (...), message: "Unexpected end of input"}message: "Unexpected end of input"stack: (...)get stack: function () { [native code] }set stack: function () { [native code] }__proto__: Error
```

Comment: Now it's your time to shine, bro.

Your function is called getHtml, right? And your ajax function is expecting a json, like you said, `dataType: 'json'`.

As I said in my answer,  some things may be happening. Be sure to verify every item in my answer, take a closer look to the jquery documentation, and log the errors. This is the farthest I can help you, now it's time for you to show your powers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things may be happening.

I don't know PHP, but is `getHtml` REALLY returning a JSON?

Maybe it is failing to parse the returning content. There are other options in the JQuery $.ajax `dataType` property.

It isn't executing the `success` function, because it might be failing at some point. Try adding an `error` function and log the data. The [JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) is very helpful and rich.

Also, try to change to  `data: JSON.stringify({ u : 'http://stackoverflow.com/' })`, at least in ASP.NET I have to do it every time.

Comment: I've updated the post and now in the console, I can see that an error has occured but I'm not sure what . It says:

Comment: The error function receives 3 parameters, and you're using only one. Modify your code to take 3 parameters, and log them all.
Also, to make your question better, post the console output so we can see what's going wrong.

Comment: More edits including updated console output , thanks for looking at this

Comment: Well, if it helps, i would appreciate if you mark it as the answer :D

Comment: I ended up changing to contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: 'html',  in the ajax function and was able to receive the html string. I didn't json encode it in the php function.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are calling the function inside the file?
You need to invoke the function by *calling* it.

```
getHtml();
```

Comment: Could you explain further?